How can I solve ImportError: cannot import name 'LangchainLLM' from 'ragas.llms' (/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ragas/llms/__init__.py)
I'm currently deploying my llm backend to Google Cloud Platform. I encountered the following error in the meeting-feedback docker container, after running docker build -t meeting-feedback . and docker run -d --name meeting-feedback -p 8000:8000 meeting-feedback. I'm using DeepEval to evaluate the outputs. Although I'm not using LangChain, it seems like DeepEval is dependent on both LangChain and Ragas, which led to the error I mentioned above.
Please help me figure out how I can resolve this issue. Thank you!
Error
ImportError: cannot import name 'LangchainLLM' from 'ragas.llms' (/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/ragas/llms/__init__.py)

Dockerfile
# Use the official Python image from the Docker Hub
FROM python:3.11

# Avoid Python from buffering stdout and stderr
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1

# Set the working directory in the container to /code
WORKDIR /code

# Copy the requirements file from your host to /code/ in the container
COPY requirements.txt /code/

# Install any dependencies
RUN pip install --no-cache-dir --upgrade -r requirements.txt

# Copy your application code (both main.py and templates.py) from the host to /code/ in the container
COPY meeting-feedback /code/

# Inform Docker that the container listens on port 8000 at runtime
EXPOSE 8000

# Command to run the application using Uvicorn. Adjust the module path to match the structure.
CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "8000", "--reload"]

requirements.txt
fastapi
openai
uvicorn
ragas==0.1.7
tiktoken==0.6.0
protobuf==3.20.3
deepeval
langchain==0.1.14
firebase_admin==6.5.0
llama_index==0.10.27
langchain-community==0.0.31
pinecone-client[grpc]==3.0.2
llama-index-vector-stores-pinecone==0.1.4

File structure
/meeting-feedback
  /meeting-feedback
  Dockerfile
  requirements.txt

